# Texted input user allowed to enter only date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm trying to achieve in the input box user can enter only numbers and the date format should be **YY/MM/DD**.

In the following example I can enter only numbers using replace method.

I want to achieve using the same method when user `keyup` the numbers format should be YY/MM/DD.

Please drop a comment for more clarification

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "input", function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\/]/g, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="YY/MM/DD">
```

Comment: Are you just wanting it to automatically format it as 01/01/2001 (with the `/`)?

Comment: What about `<input type="date">`?

Comment: @maxshuty yes that one also fine.

Comment: @David date I have separate picklist. It must be two options.

Comment: @Saravana What do you mean by "two options"? That `<input type="text">` does not have a single option, it's just a text field.

Comment: @David let's assume date picker next to the input box. Here, I want the option user keyup the date.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [this](https://codepen.io/khedut/pen/VwXNXNw).

JS

```
jQuery.fn.ForceNumericOnly =
function()
{
    return this.each(function()
    {
        $(this).keydown(function(e)
        {
            var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
            // allow backspace, tab, delete, enter, arrows, numbers and keypad numbers ONLY
            // home, end, period, and numpad decimal
            return (
                key == 8 || 
                key == 9 ||
                key == 13 ||
                key == 46 ||
                key == 110 ||
                key == 190 ||
                (key >= 35 && key <= 40) ||
                (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
                (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
        });
    });
};
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#datePicker").ForceNumericOnly();
  $('#datePicker').keyup(function(){
   let val = $(this).val()
   if(val.length==2)
      {
      val = val+'/'
      $(this).val(val)
      }
    else if (val.length==5)
      { 
        val = val+'/' 
       $(this).val(val)
      }
  })
});
```

HTML

```
<input id="datePicker" type="text" maxlength="8">
```

Comment: I already mentioned input type should be **text** only. It's not resolve my problem.

Comment: I change my answer please try this may be helps you.

Comment: this one also not useful.  the user allowed to enter only numbers and format should be **YY/MM/DD**

Comment: Please check codepen I change the code.

Comment: No luck. please come up with a actual solution. Thanks!